# Virtualmin mysql problem

Tags: mysql, apache2, vps

Today i changed some chmod settings on my VPS and since then I haven't been able to access any of my mysql databases. It's like all of them dissapeared. And I also had to reset the ssh keys.

One of the errors im getting is "SQL show character set failed : Can't create/write to file"

any idea on how i can restore everything to my previous setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know which files you've changed, the easiest solution is to restore from your latest backup.

The hard way is otherwise to figure out which permissions and ownerships each file should have and set them manually. MySQL data files should for example be owned by the MySQL user.

I have no idea about Webmin - you will benefit a lot as a sysadmin from learning the commandline.

Comment: Thanks, I would've restored it from a backup, but I dont have one. Ill try to change every permission manually.

Comment: If you lack backup routines, then surely this is not a production server?